# SQL Server - Clustered Index Key Issue on FACT Table with millions of rows

Tags: sql-server

we got a FACT Table which has got 237383163 number of rows and which has lot of duplicate data.

While running queries against this table its doing a SCAN across that many rows resulting in long execution times (bocs we haven't created clustered index).

Is there way someone can suggest - to create a clustered key using some combination of existing field along with adding any new field (like identity column)

Non-clustered index are created on table is of no help either.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- Adding a clustered index that is not unique will require a 4 byte uniqueifier
- Adding a surrogate IDENTITY column will leave you with duplicates
- A clustered index is best when narrow and numeric *espeically if* you have non-clustered indexes

First thing, de-duplicate data

Then I'd consider one of 2 things based on whether there are non-clustered indexes

1. Without NC indexes, create a unique clustered index on some or all of the FACT columns
2. With NC indexes, create an IDENTITY column and use this as the clustered index. Create a unique NC index on the FACT columns

Option 1 will be a lot smaller on disk. I've done this before for a billion+ row fact table and it shrank by 65%. There were no NC indexes.

Both options will need tested to see the effect on load and response times etc

Comment: sorry but as per the comments above - which is option 1 then ?

Comment: sorry but as per the comments above - which is option 1 then ? should I create clustered index on date field then (EVERYDAY we receive millions of rows by day) but thatss not unique

Comment: @Conrad Jagger: I've clarified the option numbers. Firstly, what identifies a fact? This would be your starting point to decide what option you need to do